# Problems with a program to make playing cards

Tags: python, class

This exercise is supposed to create a class that makes playing cards.

After 45 minutes on the phone with my (slightly scoldy) CS professor, I can't make two things stop happening here
1) The names of the list (RANKS) draws this error
NameError: global name 'RANKS' is not defined

2) The card name is supposed to be spelled out (i.e. card1 = (1 of "h" is supposed to become "Ace of Hearts") but I keep getting (1 of "h")

I don't want to drop the class. I need more direct help. She tries to be socratic which I appreciate but I am too much of a beginner. I need to learn the rules, I can't guess them. Thanks in advance.

Nancy

```
class Card(object):
    """ creates a playing card
    first: lists and dictionaries for program"""

    RANKS = ["0", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
             "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
    SUITS = {"c":"Clubs", "d":"Diamonds", "h":"Hearts", "s":"Spades"}

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):  # initializes the process
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def getRank(self):  # gets rank of card
        if self.rank in RANKS:
            RANKS[self.rank] = self.rank
            return self.rank

    def getSuit(self, SUITS=None):  # gets suit of card in a full word
        if self.suit in SUITS:
            SUITS[self.suit] = self.suit
            return self.suit


    def __str__(self):  # to make the strings to answer the problems
        return "Card is %r of %s" % (RANKS[self.rank], SUITS[self.suit])

card1 = Card(1, "h")
print (card1)
card2 = Card(3, "c")
print (card2)
```

Comment: really? you dont get an error about no global RANKS and SUITES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getRank(self):  # gets rank of card
    if self.rank in self.RANKS: #note self.RANKS
        return self.RANKS[self.rank]


def getSuit(self, SUITS=None):  # gets suit of card in a full word
    if self.suit in self.SUITS: #note use of self.SUITS
        return self.SUITS[self.suit]



def __str__(self):  # to make the strings to answer the problems
    #just call the helper methods we defined earlier
    return "Card is %s of %s" % (self.getRank(),self.getSuit())
```

Comment: Also the cause of the second issue is that the values in the `RANK` and `SUIT` dictionaries are being reassigned to their respective keys in `getRank()` and `getSuit()`

Comment: stonesam92 should I put getRank() and getSuit() into the string format? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of problems here. The most immediate one that is causing your
error is that because you have defined the list RANKS and the dictionary
SUITS inside your Card class, they must be referred to as Card.RANKS
and Card.SUITS, respectively, even from within the class.

The idea of using a simple number for rank, the using that to index
a list of rank names as text, is fine. Likewise, using a character
for suit and using that to look up a dictionary is fine. But the way
you try to do it in your getRank() and getSuit() functions is wrong.

getRank() should take the value self.rank and return the element of
the list at that index--so to see if it's valid, you need to check
the value against the legal index values, not against list values.
Secondly, the RANKS and SUITS values should be seen as constants,
so why are you trying to change them here? Lastly, since you have
no else clause, if rank value is bad, getRank() returns None.

getSuit() has all those problems, plus you have a useless argument
to pass in for no reason. Also, you want to check the suit value
against the available keys in the dictionary, so "in" is the right
way to do that.

Your **str** function should call getRank() and getSuit() so it gets
the benefit of their error handling, and possibly so that you can
change implementation later, and should use %s for both.

Here's a better approach:

```
class Card(object):

    RANKS = ["0", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
             "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
    SUITS = {"c":"Clubs", "d":"Diamonds", "h":"Hearts", "s":"Spades"}

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def getRank(self):  # gets rank of card as text
        if self.rank >= 1 and self.rank <= 13:
            return Card.RANKS[self.rank]
        else:
            return "ERROR"

    def getSuit(self):  # gets suit of card in a full word
        if self.suit in Card.SUITS:
            return Card.SUITS[self.suit]
        else:
            return "ERROR"

    def __str__(self):  # to make the strings to answer the problems
        return "Card is %s of %s" % (self.getRank(), self.getSuit())

card1 = Card(1, "h")
print (card1)
card2 = Card(3, "c")
print (card2)
```